# Copy and paste only used cells in range

Tags: excel, vba

I would really appreciate a little help. I have two open Workbooks, one is used for calculations, second one for keeping records. I used to do everything manually, but then I discovered macros and VBA, but I am a beginner. I have managed to write a code, that works for me, but I would like to have it improved.

I set a range Y22:Y37 (Sheets have same name in both workbooks), which is not always populated with values completely, but I don't know how to change the code to copy only used cells in the range. I tried to use SkipBlanks:=True, but it didn't work.

Once I copy the range I activate the second workbook, find the first empty row and paste transposed values there (starting in column B on purpose). But again, I paste the whole range Y22:Y37, which is unnecessary I think. Plus I would like to have a bottom border under used cells after pasting them. In the Picture, you can see  that meanwhile I managed to make bottom border, but I used entire row.

I somehow adjusted to my needs various codes I could find, but I know I have probably used many redundant parts of the code, but I hope someone can help me make it cleaner. Thank you very much in advance, even for reading this far. Pictures of workbooks are in links below.

```
Sub CopyVyuctovani()
Set TargetWB = Workbooks("Výdej.xlsm")
Set SourceWB = Workbooks("DPV.xlsm")
TargetSH = ActiveSheet.Name
SourceWB.Sheets(TargetSH).Range("Y22:Y37").Copy
TargetWB.Sheets(TargetSH).Activate
lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Range("B" & lMaxRows + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
Range("A" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = SourceWB.Sheets("Souhrn").Range("E30").Value
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
End Sub
```

[Source Workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWdzO.png)

[Target Workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEBWR.png)

Comment: For starters, you should fully qualify references like this: `lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row` an make sure to use `Option Explicit` which will force you to declare all of your variables.

Comment: It's probably more efficient to always copy the entire range.  Those 16 cells can be copied in one line of code.  Identifying which cells to include/exclude would require at least one additional step.  When dealing with such low volumes it's just not worth the effort.  That said you could do it by combining the [intersect function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-intersect-method-excel) with the [used range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-usedrange-property-excel).

Comment: you're right, maybe it is really not worth an effort, it is really low volume data. I will definetly remember to declare all variables, as I said, I was just happy to make the code work somehow. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Imran Malek

thank you, with this one I get no error, great :) But somehow, the copied range is pasted into line 38 of target WB (maybe it uses the last row 37 in source wb?) so I tried to activate the target WB first and it seems it works. Then I had a problem with formatting, with your code the format was used on a row that is exactly above the pasted one. So I added +1 to 1maxrows and it looks good now. The code looks like this now.

```
Sub CopyVyuctovani()

Dim targetWB As Workbook
Dim sourceWb As Workbook
Dim targetSH As String
Dim lmaxrows As Long

Set targetWB = Workbooks("Výdej.xlsm")
Set sourceWb = Workbooks("DPV.xlsm")
targetSH = ActiveSheet.Name

sourceWb.Sheets(targetSH).Range("Y22:Y37").Copy

With targetWB.Sheets(targetSH)
    .Activate
    lmaxrows = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("B" & lmaxrows + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=True
    .Range("A" & lmaxrows + 1).Value = sourceWb.Sheets("Souhrn").Range("E30").Value
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    .Range("A" & lmaxrows + 1 & ":Q" & lmaxrows + 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Range("A" & lmaxrows + 1 & ":Q" & lmaxrows + 1).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is more or less the same but it will fix your two problems

```
Sub CopyVyuctovani()

    Dim targetWB As Workbook
    Dim sourceWb As Workbook
    Dim targetSH As String
    Dim lmaxrows As Long

    Set targetWB = Workbooks("Výdej.xlsm")
    Set sourceWb = Workbooks("DPV.xlsm")
    targetSH = ActiveSheet.Name

    sourceWb.Sheets(targetSH).Range("Y22:Y37").Copy

    With targetWB.Sheets(targetSH)
        lmaxrows = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("B" & lmaxrows + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=True
        .Range("A" & lmaxrows + 1).Value = sourceWb.Sheets("Souhrn").Range("E30").Value
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        .Range("A" & lmaxrows & ":Q" & lmaxrows).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Range("A" & lmaxrows & ":Q" & lmaxrows).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this looks very much better. But I get an error: Run Time Error '424' object required. When I click Debug, this line is highlighted:
Set targetSH = ActiveSheet.Name

Comment: @Tireur I made a small mistake that I have corrected now.Give it another go.